# shell script to create multiple AWS IAM users

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

users="test1@aaa.com test2@aaa.com test3@aaa.com test4@aaa.com"

for user in $users
do
  aws iam create-user --user-name "$user"
  aws iam attach-user-policy --user-name="$user" --policy-arn=arn:aws:iam::435501576190:policy/S3-Access-sftp-release-binaries
  aws iam create-login-profile --user-name="$user" --password='4l)C=Tb(Tl$I' --password-reset-required
done
```

I want to automate above user creation and I have a text file with user names. How to automate ?

Comment: Tell me the password you have in your question there isn't your real one.

Comment: It isn't real one. I want to generate random password for each users too.

Comment: Seems like you already solved your question.  Congratulations!  If not, then please let us know what your issues are.  Or is is just the `users=$(cat my_users_file.txt)` which you are missing?

Comment: Yes Im missing that one. I have users.txt file and I want to create IAM users for those users.

Comment: I want to generate a random password for each user. Could you please tell me how to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

gen_pw() {
  head -c 9 /dev/urandom | uuencode -m - | head -2 | tail -1 |  tr '1IlO0' '$/%&#'
}

while read user  # I assume a users text file containing one user per line here
do
  password=$(gen_pw)
  aws iam create-user --user-name "$user"
  aws iam attach-user-policy --user-name="$user" --policy-arn=arn:aws:iam::435501576190:policy/S3-Access-sftp-release-binaries
  aws iam create-login-profile --user-name="$user" --password="$password" --password-reset-required
  echo "created $user with password $password"
done < my_users_file.txt
```

You need to have `uuencode` installed for this.  You can also use `base64` instead: `.../urandom | base64 - | tr ...` (no need for `head` and `tail` then).